# Shortcut to execute application commands in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

When I was using Ubuntu 14.04 I could press <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key to run any current application command. For example, If I were using Sublime Text and wanted to run some command related to that application, I just would press<kbd>Alt</kbd>   and type my command.
But, since I switched over to Ubuntu 18.04 this shortcut does not work any longer. I searched for it in the Internet, but so far was unable to find any substitute key to that purpose.

Would anyone be so kind to tell me whether there is any equivalent command in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: It did not work for me George.

Comment: What? It does for me, but so I get you right. You want to be able to say launch application from this window that should pop up?

Comment: No, what I want is to run a shortcut belonging to the current application. Example, let's say I want to change text syntax from plain text to python inside a Sublime program tab, I would then press 'Alt' key in Ubuntu 14.04 and type 'python', then I would see the option to do that as a application command.

Comment: Ok I see never used that...then it's a sublime thing then?